# How to show steps of "For" command

Tags: list-manipulation

I wrote the command:

```
list = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {9, 3}];
For[i = 1, i <= m, i++, element=Total[ list[[i]] ] ]
```

How can I make every step visible? If I write

```
list = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {9, 3}];
For[i = 1, i <= m, i++, element = Total[ list[[i]] ] ] 
element
```

it gives me only the last value. My goal is to see "element" at every step.

Comment: Have a look at `Print[]`. Maybe `Sow[]`/`Reap[]` too.

Comment: Use `element=Total /@ list` Now the terms of `element` are the 9 sums, each consisting of 3 elements.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my comment: this is a perfect example of a common mistake that beginners make when using Mathematica (please don't take offense Marco, none is intended!) The thought process may be something like this: "I know how `Total` works, and I want to get the total of each sublist, so I'll use a loop structure (such as `For`, `Do`, or `Table`) to make Total work on each sublist."

Mathematica provides a better way to conceptualize this. What you want to do is to apply (or in this case, `Map`) the `Total` function to the correct level of the expression. In this case, it is the default level, so you can simply write

```
element=Total /@ list
```

Comment: ...or `Total @ Transpose @ list`  :)